# Can PowerShell use System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: powershell, parallel.foreach

Preface: I know PS can multithread in many different ways, my question is whether there is a syntax that allows PowerShell to access the ForEach (and For) methods in System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel. For example, I have the following very simple c# example where list:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    list, 
    (x) => 
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} has {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, x);
    });
```

Now I have been trying to find the right syntax to rewrite in PowerShell. I put my code in a scriptblock. It seems I can't figure out how to replace the lambda syntax, normally calling &$scriptblock is the way this is done. The following is one of many variations I have tried:

```
 $thread = [System.Threading.Thread]
 $parallel = [System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel]
 $scriptblock = {param($x) Write-Host("Thread {0} has {1}" -f 
 $thread::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, $x)}
 $parallel::ForEach(
    $list, 
    ($x),
    {
        &$scriptblock -item $x
    })
```

Is there a way to get the Parallel.ForEach to work in PowerShell?

Comment: `ForEach<TSource>(....)` is a *generic method* so you'll need [Calling generic static method in PowerShell](//stackoverflow.com/q/4241985). Not really worth it if you ask me. Better use an alternative.

Comment: Syntax is the easy part. You just need to cast `ScriptBlock` to right delegate type. Main problem you have to solve: PowerShell code need `Runspace` to run in it, and default `TaskScheduler` do not provide one for auxiliary threads.

Comment: @wOxxOm - You're right that doesn't seem worth it. I was mainly curious than anything. Thank you!